# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, drag-and-drop

I am using two Angular(2+) tools: ng2-file-upload and angular2-img-cropper.

I am trying to use ng2-file-upload's Dropzone to load an image in angular2-img-cropper's cropping tool.
I actually can load the selected image in the crop tool it if I change the Input File (HTMLElement), but it fails with the drag-drop zone.

Here is how I can do it with the input:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="file" id="file-name" 
                    ng2FileSelect 
                    [uploader]="uploader"
                    (change)="fileChangeListener($event, cropper)"/>
```

**TS:**

```
fileChangeListener($event : any, cropperComp: ImageCropperComponent) {

    this.cropper = cropperComp;

    let image = new Image();
    var file:File = $event.target.files[0];
    var myReader:FileReader = new FileReader();
    var that = this;

    myReader.onloadend = function (loadEvent: any) {
        image.src = loadEvent.target.result;
        that.cropper.setImage(image);
    };
    myReader.readAsDataURL(file);

}
```

As I said, this works well.

However, when I try to use the Dropzone I get this error:

***ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined [...] at ProfileComponent.fileChangeListener***

**HTML** (dropzone):

```
<div ng2FileDrop
                    [ngClass]="{'nv-file-over': hasBaseDropZoneOver}"
                    (fileOver)="fileOverBase($event)"
                    [uploader]="uploader"
                    class="well my-drop-zone"     
                    (onFileDrop)="fileChangeListener($event, cropper)"
                    >
                    Base drop zone
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var file:File = $event.target.files[0];
```

should be:

```
var file:File = $event.files[0];
```

Comment: I tried it earlier but the console says: **Cannot read property '0' of undefined**

Comment: @phse ` this.onFileDrop.emit(transfer.files);` I read the soruce code, the onFileDrop emits files directly. You can print out  `$event` and check the details

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time. I am a newbie, I do not get where to try that.

Comment: add `console.log($event);` right above your existing code `    var file:File = $event.target.files[0];` and check what have been printed use your devTool

Comment: It seems it is passed as a FileList.
`FileList {0: File(1874089), length: 1}
0
:
File(1874089) {name: "panda.jpg", lastModified: 1520284581576, lastModifiedDate: Mon Mar 05 2018 16:16:21 GMT-0500 (Hora estándar del Este), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 1874089, …}
length
:
1
__proto__
:
FileList`

If if I try to change var file:FileList then myReader.readAsDataURL(file) gives an error saying: _it is not assignable to parameter of type 'Blob'. Property 'size' is missing in type 'FileList'._

Thanks for your time, I guess it's hard to work with a student :O